# Twitter TypeAhead - MouseOver suggestions puts suggestion in input.tt-query

Tags: jquery, twitter-typeahead

In Standard Twitter TypeAhead I have following behaviour:

When a user starts typing, suggestions are popping up and when he hits enter, he's being redirected to the detailed search page with the text he typed in used as an url parameter ?query=[text]. This is as expected and Ok.

When the user puts the mouse over a suggestion before he hits enter, it automatically puts the title of this suggestion in the tt-query-input (not visible) and when hitting enter, the search query is the title of the suggestion instead of what he has typed. 
How can I avoid this behaviour?

I added this code to redirect when enter is clicked (where txtQuery is the id I added to the with class 'typeahead tt-query:

```
   $('#txtQuery').bind("enterKey", function (e) {
         var url = '/?query=' + $('#txtQuery').val();
         window.location.href = url;
     });
     $('#txtQuery').keyup(function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             $(this).trigger("enterKey");
         }
     });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is "standard tt" behaviour. What have you tried? Code?

Comment: i added the code which redirects when enter is being clicked. all the rest is standard tt version 0.9.3

Comment: In typeahead, pressing enter should select the value under the cursor and fire the enterKey event as well. This seems like normal behaviour to me from a usability standpoint - I see what has been offered and press enter to have the input box retain whats under the cursor. I wonder what your reasoning is why to change it.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid. Pressing enter when the mouse is (or was) over a suggestion shouldn't put that suggested title in the input. The suggestions are links to pages, clicking on them will lead the user there. when these suggestions aren't what the user is looking for, enter should lead him to a more detailed page with the search query he entered.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, something unexpected happens when you hover over the suggestions. For whatever reason, hovering will change your value in the input DOM. You could try preventing actions performed on the event like this:

```
$('.twitter-typeahead').on('mouseover', '.tt-suggestion', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // verify input
  console.log($('#txtQuery').val());
});
```

EDIT:

In the same manner, you can "unbind" the keydown events from the '.tt-suggestion' items to prevent `enter` from selecting and submitting.

HTH

Comment: i couldn't really avoid that tt sets - once the mouse was over a suggestion - the suggestion in the span-element which is added after the input.tt-query. Using your mouse-over event I put the user-query in a hidden input and use this one when redirecting. not very elegenat, but for the moment it works..